# How to add polygon along polyline?

Tags: android, polygon, google-maps-android-api-2, polyline

I am a new developer of Android. I want to develop map application. I want to draw the polyline on the map similar to get direction on Google Ma. After drawing a polyline can I draw a polygon along the polyline? I do not know how to do it. Please give me an example or some solution. Thank you very much and Sorry with my English. Is it possible to do it ?

This is picture
[https://www.dropbox.com/s/nmusjt6fp880akf/20-Jun-13%204-05-25%20PM.png][1]

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204174/polygon-polyline. Maybe try be more descriptive or make a screenshot of what you want to achieve and most certainly you should put here parts of what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Canvas` `Path` `Point` Class to Draw a PolyLine on Google Map. Also you need to look on  [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline.html)for reference.

```
List<Overlay> mapOverlay;

  protected onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceStae){

     //Do the rest stuffs

      mapOverlay = mapView.getOverLays();

      mapOverlay.add(new MyOverlay());


     }


class MyOverLay extends Overlay{

       public MyOverlay(){}

       ArrayList<GeoPoint> points = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();

       public void draw(Canvas canvas,MapView mv, boolean shadow){
            super.draw(canvas,mv,shadow);

         Paint mPaint = new Paint();
         mPiant.setColor(Color.RED);
          //set strokewidth and all function depending upon you how you want to give a look                 

          //on Polyline.

        GeoPOint gp1 = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1000000.0), (int) (lon * 1000000.0));
        GeoPOint gp2 = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1000000.0), (int) (lon * 1000000.0));
        GeoPOint gp3 = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1000000.0), (int) (lon * 1000000.0));
       GeoPOint gp4 = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1000000.0), (int) (lon * 1000000.0));



     points.add(gp1);
     points.add(gp2);
     points.add(gp3);
     points.add(gp4);

     //Then take two points class object:

    Point point1 = new Point();

    Point point2 = new Point();

    Path path = new Path();

    for(int i = 0; i<points.size(); i++){

      projection.toPixel(points.get(i),point1);
      projection.toPixel(points.get(i+1),point2);

      path.moveTo(point2.x,point2.y);
       path.lineTo(point1.x,point1.y);

     }

   canvas.drawPath(path, mPoint);


}
```